# Create table head using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to create table head.How can i write using document.write. I try `<thread>` tag but it's not working?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function btnCallWCF_onclick() {
                Service.getproprttydatasdata(onSuccess);
            }
            function onSuccess(response) {
                debugger;
                document.write('<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5"><thead><tr>Address</tr><tr>Address</tr><tr>Address</tr>')
                for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                    document.write('<tr>')
                    document.write('<tr>' + i + '</td>')
                    document.write('<td>' + response[i].Address + '</td>')
                    document.write('<td>' + response[i].Address + '</td>')
                    document.write('<td>' + response[i].Address + '</td>')
                    document.write('</tr>')
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: missing end thead tag

Comment: Basically I using wcf service to get 2 million record.Client need to show all the record at a time.It's really taff load all the  record. Any other Solution ??????????

Comment: dan it's not working if i use end tag

Comment: Doesn't anyone use [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function btnCallWCF_onclick() {
            Service.getproprttydatasdata(onSuccess);
        }
        function onSuccess(response) {
            debugger;
            document.write('<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5"><thead><tr><th>Address</th><th>Address</th><th>Address</th><th>Address</th></tr></thead>'); // There is 1 row with 3 headings.
            for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                document.write('<tr>')
                document.write('<td>' + i + '</td>') // Changed <tr> to <td>
                document.write('<td>' + response[i].Address + '</td>')
                document.write('<td>' + response[i].Address + '</td>')
                document.write('<td>' + response[i].Address + '</td>')
                document.write('</tr>')
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: The code to write the table head is correct, I tried it on chrome.
Is your table geting printed, if not can you please share any console error ?

Comment: yes table is printed but column name is not showing

Comment: on which browser are you trying ?
Please try on google chrome, I have tested it on chrome.
It is working perfectly fine :)